# Arch Linux must synchronize certain package data with repository server

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

How to force Arch linux to synchronize a certain packages data with repository server configured as `{repo_title_name}`  in `pacman.conf`?

I tried `sudo pacman  -Sy {repo_title_name}` and it resulted in:

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core                             265.5 KiB   103 KiB/s 00:03 [##################################] 100%
 extra
```

It keeps downloading each package as usual.

How can I do this?

Comment: Really not sure what you're asking here – you're talking about one thing but demonstrating another. Are you trying to limit which repository databases will be refreshed, or are you trying to limit which actual packages will be downloaded, or what?